# Use of Direct Queries in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently studying SQLite and I have found that it uses various classes like ContentValues for insertion and updation... I was wondering whether I have to follow the given way or can I write a normal SQL query and use db.execSQL() method to execute them?
Will it bring any inconsistency to my database because with these all "extra" steps doesnt it stop the flow of the query and I feel it would be faster if we use a query directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do any SQL command you want with `db.execSQL` except `select` command or any other SQL command that return data (you use `db.rawQuery()` for this). The classes used are helper classes that make it easy for you to manipulate DBs (try inserting 100 rows with 20 columns each using `ContentValues` and `db.execSQL` and you will get the point). For small tables it will not differ much (and you will not cause inconsistecies), however, for large tables with inputs that depend on user interface or use calculations, it might be useful to have a class like ContentValues with its helper methods.

Comment: Okay insertion is fine with ContentValues no problem with that but when I want to retrieve rows using a field that matches a particular value then?? like when I need to use a where command..??

Comment: Use `Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select blah from FOO_TABLE WHERE blah LIKE value",null)` or use `Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`. Then use this `cursor` to fill an Adapter and a `ListView` or to loop through values

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely use this way like using

```
  myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('fffff', 'numb', 20)");
```

to insert values but only when you are using database for small queries.
Also there are some flaws using direct methods which gets removed using ContentValues
For example,try to insert a blob into the database using this method ,you will get a null bitmap while converting the retrieved data to bitmap.But when you insert using ContentValues,you will get the correct data i.e you will be able to convert that into Bitmap.